# PS/2 Mouse not recognized at Windows XP startup

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, ps2

I have a PS/2 Logitech optical mouse connected through a KVM to a system running Windows XP.  When the system starts up the mouse will not respond (does not appear to be getting power, optical light not on).  If I unplug the mouse and plug it back in it works (yes I shouldn't really do that with a PS/2 mouse but it doesn't seem to be connected so I'm not that concerned about it).  Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 for not doing or stating basic trobleshooting a) try/test it without kvm b)try/teset with, another mouse, they are only $5  c)since you could simply test for power, you can try plugging a keyboard into the mouse socket and see if it doesnt always get power. a ps2 keyboard's numlock and a few other lights, will fiash once when it receives power,

Comment: Basic troubleshooting has in fact been done.  The socket clearly has power as simply unplugging and plugging the mouse back in caused the mouse to work properly.  A USB mouse plugged directly in seems to work without issue.  The mouse currently plugged in is the replacement mouse.